# How to dismiss a customized UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a customized `UISearchController` in the home page. When an user navigating to another screen, I just want to dismiss the `UISearchController`, if it's active. Any help?

```
if customSearchController.isActive {
    customSearchController.dismiss(animated: true) { doAlert() }
} else {
    doAlert()
}
```

Comment: So it isn't dismissing? Does `isActive` act as expected.

Comment: It's not dismissing and also, I tried to set `isActive` true, but no hope.